# SwiftUI view sizing is broken when added to UITableViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, swiftui, uikit

I need to display a SwiftUI view in an existing `UITableViewController`, as the `tableHeaderView`. However, it seems that the sizing of the SwiftUI view is broken when it is added to a `UITableViewController`.

If I simply convert my SwiftUI View to a `UIView` using a `UIHostingController` and set it to the `tableHeaderView`, the view is displayed off screen:

```
func addHeaderView() {
    let view = VerticalTextStack()
    let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
    tableView.tableHeaderView = hostingController.view
}
```

[Incorrect layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDGxs.png)

To counteract this, I've tried to fix the height of the view several different ways. Adding an `NSLayoutConstraint` didn't do anything. When setting `tableHeaderView.frame.size` manually, the results were better, since at least now the view is displayed on-screen, but the multiline `Text`s become single-line and truncated.

As you can see here, the 2nd `Text` gets truncated:

[image: Truncated Text]

Here's a simplified example showcasing the problem:

```
/// `UITableViewController` displaying a `UIView` as its `tableHeaderView`
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"
    let data = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    let themeManager = AppThemeManager()

    // MARK: - UIViewController lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
        addHeaderView()
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        fixTableHeaderViewSize()
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDelegate
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        data.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - SwiftUI view
    func fixTableHeaderViewSize() {
        guard let tableHeaderView = tableView?.tableHeaderView else { return }
        let expectedHeight = tableHeaderView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingExpandedSize).height
        let expectedSize = CGSize(width: tableHeaderView.frame.width, height: expectedHeight)

        tableHeaderView.frame.size = expectedSize
    }

    func addHeaderView() {
        let view = VerticalTextStack()
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
        tableView.tableHeaderView = hostingController.view
    }
}

private struct VerticalTextStack: View {
    let data = ["First", "I am a very long text that only fits in multiple lines. I still continue.", "Third"]
    let themeManager = AppThemeManager()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            ForEach(data, id: \.self) { value in
                Text(value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried moving `addHeaderView` to other UIViewController functions, such as `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, but that didn't change anything.

Setting `lineLimit` to `nil` or any large number on the `Text` inside `VerticalTextStack` and adding `.layoutPriority(.greatestFiniteMagnitude)` to the `Text` did not make the `Text` multiline either.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution.

Change your add header view funcation with this.

```
func addHeaderView() {
    
    let view = VerticalTextStack()
    let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
    
    let headerViewMain = UIView()
    headerViewMain.backgroundColor = .red
    headerViewMain.addSubview(hostingController.view)
    
    hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    let constraints = [
        hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerViewMain.topAnchor),
        hostingController.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerViewMain.leftAnchor),
        headerViewMain.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hostingController.view.bottomAnchor),
        headerViewMain.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hostingController.view.rightAnchor)
    ]
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    
    headerViewMain.frame.size.height = headerViewMain.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    headerViewMain.frame.size.width = headerViewMain.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).width
    self.tableHeaderView = headerViewMain
    
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.setNeedsLayout()
    
    self.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: This code does not even compile, since you seem to have assumed this is inside a `UITableView` subclass rather than a `UITableViewController `subclass. However, even if I fix those issues, the multiline text is still single line and truncates. Did you even test your proposed solution? Btw, calling `setNeedsLayout` _after_ `layoutIfNeeded` is a horrible idea and why would you want to call `reloadData` after setting the `tableHeaderView`?

Comment: For the first one,  I forgot this is UITableViewController class. and yes I tested the code and it will create an issue in multiline and I don't think calling setNeedsLayout after layoutIfNeeded is a horrible. and for reload it's fine to not call. I used another existing demo so that why reload code is there.

Comment: and multi-line issue solved by this line
```Text(value).frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).fixedSize().lineLimit(nil)```

Comment: Well if your code still has the issue with multiline text how is this a solution to my problem at all? The multiline text issue is the only thing I couldn't resolve, so this isn't any better than my original code. Calling `setNeedsLayout` _before_ `layoutIfNeeded` might make sense, but calling it after makes no sense at all. You first tell UIKit to update the UI if necessary and only then tell it that it is necessary to update?

Comment: @DávidPásztor check my second comment for multiline text issue.

Comment: I can't use `frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)` in my real view, which is more complex than just a simple `VStack` of `Text`s. I need the width to be dynamic as well as the height.